# How to detect if the device is a smartphone or tablet in libgdx?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, libgdx, scene2d

I want a certain ui element in my scene2d ui to scaledown on larger screens(not necessarily higher *resolution* screens). Its pretty straight forward in Android layout but how to get it working in libgdx. Maybe some API that I am missing ?

Can it be done through interface in Androidactivity?
Current solution I can think of is declaring a flag in differend layout folders(values-sw600 etc) and fetch it in androidactivity in oncreate() and then pass it to libgdx through an interface.
Please suggest if there is a better way

Comment: Take a look at the Libgdx `Viewport`s, maybe you find something there.

Comment: @Springrbua i am already using viewports but there seems to be nothing to target a large screen. Anyways i got it working flawlessly by declaring some boolean flags in xml for large screen and then fetch them in Game class through interfacr.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still curious on a easier method to solve this you can use the LibGDX method `Gdx.graphics.getDensity();`. This returns the pixel density of the screen and can be converted into an inches measurement.
Calculation:

```
public float getScreenSizeInches () {
    //According to LibGDX documentation; getDensity() returns a scalar value for 160dpi.
    float dpi = 160 * Gdx.graphics.getDensity();
    float widthInches = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / dpi;
    float heightInches = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / dpi;

    //Use the pythagorean theorem to get the diagonal screen size
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(widthInches, 2) + Math.pow(heightInches, 2));
}
```

I haven't actually tested this but, in theory, it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: This doesn't work in mobile browser, it just returns a constant regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented by vedi0boy does not handle the PC platform correctly since `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` does only return the size of the viewport, not the screen itself.

Here is a working solution for all platforms

```
public static double getScreenSizeInches()
{
    // Use the primary monitor as baseline
    // It would also be possible to get the monitor where the window is displayed
    Graphics.Monitor primary = Gdx.graphics.getPrimaryMonitor();
    Graphics.DisplayMode displayMode = Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode(primary);

    float dpi = 160 * Gdx.graphics.getDensity();
    float widthInches = displayMode.width / dpi;
    float heightInches = displayMode.height / dpi;

    //Use the pythagorean theorem to get the diagonal screen size
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(widthInches, 2) + Math.pow(heightInches, 2));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in mobile browser since Gdx.graphics.getDensity() isn't a valid value on the mobile browser platform.

Comment: In case of browser applications you can use "Window.getClientWidth()" and "Window.getClientHeight()" inside your GWTApplication and pass that to the core application